# Python Class returning 'None' (Not desirable)

Tags: python

When birthframe is 0 everything is ok (not getting any None), but when its more than 0 like 0.6 initial frames are 'None', which I don't want the Class to return.

I am getting 'None' frame when I am calling the Class NumberAnimation. I want to hide 'None', but within the function (look for in the below) `print "newval", (newval + noise_val)` , the 'None' statement isn't returning (desirable). I want the Class not return 'None' as I call the Class formally (see extreme below How I called the Class). It was Python3 code which I am porting into Python 2.7, which could be a factor that I am getting strange results.

```
from backports.functools_lru_cache import lru_cache

from vectortween.Animation import Animation
from vectortween.Mapping import Mapping
from vectortween.Tween import Tween


class NumberAnimation(Animation):
    """
    class to animate the value of a number between startframe and stopframe
    tweening optionally can be applied (default is None, which means linear animation)
    """

    def __init__(self, frm, to, tween=None, noise_fn=None):
        """

        :param frm: start value 
        :param to: end value
        :param tween: optional tweening function (default: linear)
        :param noise_fn: optional noise function (default: None)
          noise_fn needs to accept two parameters: a value (frm <= value <= to) and a time (0 <= time <= 1)
          if the noise_fn uses parameter t the noise will be animated in time; by accepting but ignoring t,
          the noise is only spatial
        """
        super(NumberAnimation, self).__init__(frm, to)
        if tween is None:
            tween = ['linear']
        self.noise_fn = noise_fn
        self.T = Tween(*tween)

    #@lru_cache(maxsize=1000)
    def make_frame(self, frame, birthframe, startframe, stopframe, deathframe, noiseframe=None):
        """
        animation happens between startframe and stopframe
        the value is None before aliveframe, and after deathframe
         * if aliveframe is not specified it defaults to startframe
         * if deathframe is not specified it defaults to stopframe

        initial value is held from aliveframe to startframe

        final value is held from stopfrome to deathframe 
        """

        if birthframe is None:
            birthframe = startframe
        if deathframe is None:
            deathframe = stopframe
        if frame < birthframe:
            return None
        if frame > deathframe:
            return None
        if frame < startframe:
            return self.frm
        if frame > stopframe:
            return self.to

        t = self.T.tween2(frame, startframe, stopframe)
        newval = Mapping.linlin(t, 0, 1, self.frm, self.to)
        if self.noise_fn is not None:
            if noiseframe is not None:
                nf = noiseframe
            else:
                nf = t
            noise_val = self.noise_fn(newval, nf)
        else:
            noise_val = 0

        print "newval", (newval + noise_val)
        return newval + noise_val
```

I am calling the Class here: The print statement, however, is returning 'None', which I don't want to return to.

```
n = NumberAnimation(frm=0, to=110, tween=["easeOutBounce"])

for i in range(100):

    print (n.make_frame(frame=i/20, birthframe=0.6, startframe=0, 
                        stopframe=5, deathframe=5))
```

I am getting results like that:

```
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
newval 33.275
33.275
newval 33.275
33.275
newval 33.275
33.275
newval 33.275
33.275
newval 33.275
33.275
newval 33.275
```

Comment: @tgikal, the same class is used in several other places, so I need to solve that issue here, if possible.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You're returning `None` and printing it. If you don't want to then don't!

Comment: If you don't want `make_frame` to return None, why are you having it return None? Can't you just change what it returns?

Comment: I have posted the results I am getting.

Comment: You explicitly use ``if frame < birthframe: return None``, why are you surprised to get ``None`` if ``birthframe`` is bigger than ``frame``? Your doctoring explicitly says the value is ``None`` in this condition.

Answer (score 0):

Your method `make_frame` is actually returning None in two of the cases (which is the reason why you are getting None)

```
if frame < birthframe:
    return None
if frame > deathframe:
    return None
```

If you don't want to see None just return something else in those cases (like an empty string `''`)